# Android Q - Delete Media (Audio) File

Tags: java, android, android-contentresolver, android-10.0, scoped-storage

I've been trying to get my app to be able to delete an audio file. However, after trying many possible solutions, I couldn't really find one that works.

Here is my solution so far:

```
public static void deleteFiles(List<Track> tracks, Context context,
                                   final MutableLiveData<IntentSender> deletionIntentSenderLD){

        final Uri AUDIO_URI = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        for(Track t : tracks){
            try {

                context.getContentResolver().delete(ContentUris
                        .withAppendedId(AUDIO_URI, t.getUriId()), null, null);

            }catch (SecurityException securityException) {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {

                    if (securityException instanceof RecoverableSecurityException) {

                        deletionIntentSenderLD
                                .postValue(((RecoverableSecurityException) securityException)
                                        .getUserAction().getActionIntent().getIntentSender());

                    } else
                        throw securityException;

                } else
                    throw securityException;

            }

        }

    }
```

When the try block fails a SecurityException is catch then the IntentSender is passed to the live data that is observed in a fragment:

```
audioViewModel.getDeletionIntentSenderLD().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(),
            intentSender -> {
                try {
                    startIntentSenderForResult(intentSender, DELETE_PERMISSION_REQUEST,
                            null, 0 ,0, 0,
                            null);
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
```

I've tried implementing the onRequestPermissionResult() method but that doesn't do anything. I've also tried deleting the files using `File file = new File()`, however, due to the changes made to Android 10, I didn't expect it to work.

Comment: `trying to get my app to be able to delete an audio file` To who belongs that file? Who put it there. Android 11 is very restrictive concerning the owner of the file. Further: Why are you coming with a whole list where we cannot see whats in it. Why noty a simple example tryinng to delete one uri!? ANd why do you need live data and fragments for a delete task?

Comment: "To who belongs that file?" - to the user, its a sharable media file and not app specific. "Android 11 is very restrictive..." - I understand that. Just to be clear Android Q is 10. "Why are you coming with a whole list" - for bulk delete. "where we cannot see whats in it" - Don't think that matters *except* that fact that the uri id in Track is from the content resolver MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID. Didn't want to bloat this post. "why do you need live data and fragments..." to use the startIntentSenderForResult. The first code block is not in an activity or fragment, rather in a util class.

Comment: If you want help how to delete a file then take one and not a list full. Further dont mess atround with lifedata and fragments. Just post simple code that can be copy/pasted to try.

Comment: I've changed the param to take a single object rather than a list but it still didn't work. What's odd is that if I remove context.getContentResolver().delete() then compile and then add it back in, the delete function works perfectly (whether is takes a list or not) but *only in the first delete*. After that it ceases to work properly. None-the-less, I've come up with a solution that seems to have worked for both Android 10 and 11. Just a question though, I understand that you are enforced to use scoped storage in android 11 but is requestLegacyExternalStorage available in android 10 forever?

Comment: As for my solution, I will post it tomorrow (and possibly close this thread) but I am interested in seeing solutions to delete files using scope storage in android 10. Android 11 is not a problem as it has a cleaner way of deleting files.

Comment: I hope requesting legacy for Q is forever. For Android 11 devices you can still create folders and files in all public directories. No, scoped storage is not enforced there. Waiting for your post..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after many Google searches, I've come to the conclusion that the best approach (to my knowledge) is to simply turn off scoped storage for Android Q (10).

Here, I'll provide two solutions. The first is the one where I turn it off and the second is the one where scope storage is still enable. However, a thing you should note is that the second solution is a little buggy, at times it actually does delete both the actual media file and updates the Media Store, but most times it simply deletes from the Media Store only. Obviously, this isn't a very good solution as on reboot your application would then load those files back in because the Media Store would scan for them.

**Solution 1 - Turn off Scoped Storage**

For this solution you can still target Android 11. All you have to do is go to the `build.gradle` file at the Module Level and set the `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to `30`.

After that, you go into the `AndroidManifest.xml` and have the uses-permission and application tag set up like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="29"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage"/>

<application
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    ...
```

After having done that, you could use the Content Resolver to delete the media file (and update the Media Store) and you do not have to worry about catching a security exception like its said in the Android docs. Your implementation for Android 11s delete operation should not be affected.

**Solution-ish 2 - Turn on Scoped Storage**

Firstly, in your manifest ensure that the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions `maxSdkVersion` is set to `28`. Also ensure that `requestLegacyExternalStorage` is set to `false` (don't think this is required). Then simply copy the code in my original post. You do not require a Live Data if you are doing the delete operation from your activity/fragment. But you should note that `startIntentSenderForResult()` requires an activity.

But as I mentioned before, I did experience some bugs with this. The most frustrating thing about this solution though is that it does not delete the actual file but instead deletes the entry from the Media Store. Maybe this has something to do with the fact that @blackapps mentioned, which is that you cannot bulk delete and I might have implemented it slightly wrong. Nevertheless, this is horrible for user experience if bulk deletion is impossible in Android 10.

The tutorials I followed for this are:

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#remove-item

https://www.raywenderlich.com/9577211-scoped-storage-in-android-10-getting-started#toc-anchor-007

https://www.solutionanalysts.com/blog/scoped-storage-in-android-10/

**Side Note - Delete on Android 11**

To delete on Android 11 you just need to call `createDeleteRequest()` which should return a `PendingIntent`. From this `PendingIntent` you could get the `IntentSender` by using `getIntentSender`. Pass this intent sender to the activity/fragment then call `startIntentSenderForResult()` in your activity/fragment. This pops up a dialog to the user asking them if the application can delete a file. If the user gives permission the system goes ahead and deletes the file and updates the Media Store.

**Side Side Note - Scoped Storage, Android 10 and Future**

From everything I've seen, it seems to suggest that scoped storage is only enforced in Android 11 but I'm not entirely sure if the legacy option would still be available in Android 10 indefinitely. But I would have to do more research on this...